# c# metro app: how to drop image which is dragged over another image

Tags: c#, image, drag-and-drop, windows-8

I have a simple metro style app where I want to drag 16 images and drop them over another image. The other image should set its source to the soure of the dragged image.

this is the dragging method:

```
    private void ManipulationDelta_Pic(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = e.OriginalSource as Image;
        if (img != null)
        {
            var ct = img.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
            if (ct != null)
            {
                ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
                ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the xaml with the images, which should be the drop darget (imagine 16 of them):

```
        </Grid>

    <Grid Margin="377,0,371,23" Background="Cornsilk" Grid.Row="1" Height="600" Width="600" AllowDrop="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border x:Name="z1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Beige"  AllowDrop="true">
            <Image  x:Name="puzz1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Source="Assets/win8001.jpg" AllowDrop="True"/>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
```

and there are the images which should be dropped (also 16 of them).

```
<Image x:Name="sidePics1"  Width="150" Height="150" ManipulationMode="All" Margin="1311,507,-95,-29" Grid.Row="1" ManipulationDelta="ManipulationDelta_Pic" Drop="Drop_Pic">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
         </Image>
```

I don't know how to solve this, I'm very new in Metro App programming. I know it should be something with DragOver, DragEnter, DragLeave and Drop Event but I don't know what to do with that.

I need help, Thank you.

Comment: Can you state a bit more concisely what the problem is and what the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article on doing drag & drop in Silverlight a few years ago.  This should help.

http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2009/07/05/day-5-silverlight-drag-and-drop/